# E4 NatTable dynamic context menu

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4, nattable

I want the context menu items of my natTable to change, depending on the selected row. How can I achieve this ?

UPDATE: this works so far, i have A and B showing on even/uneven lines. My next question is: does this mean that I have to call these methods for every menu item groups ?

```
myPopupMenuBuilder.withMenuItemProvider("A", new IMenuItemProvider() {
        @Override
        public void addMenuItem(NatTable paramNatTable, Menu paramMenu) {
            MenuItem row = new MenuItem(paramMenu, SWT.PUSH);
            row.setText("A");
        }
    }).withMenuItemProvider("B", new IMenuItemProvider() {
        @Override
        public void addMenuItem(NatTable paramNatTable, Menu paramMenu) {
            MenuItem row = new MenuItem(paramMenu, SWT.PUSH);
            row.setText("B");
        }
    }).withVisibleState("A", new IMenuItemState() {
        @Override
        public boolean isActive(NatEventData paramNatEventData) {
            return paramNatEventData.getRowPosition() % 2 == 0;
        }
    }).withVisibleState("B", new IMenuItemState() {
        @Override
        public boolean isActive(NatEventData paramNatEventData) {
            return paramNatEventData.getRowPosition() % 2 == 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: ISelectionProvider isp = new RowSelectionProvider<Person>(cecTable.getSelectionLayer(), cecTable.getDataProvider());
        MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();
        menuManager.add(new Separator(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
        getSite().registerContextMenu("org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.example.contextmenu", menuManager, isp);
        PopupMenuBuilder popupMenu = new PopupMenuBuilder(cecTable.getNatTable(), menuManager.createContextMenu(cecTable.getNatTable()));
        popupMenu.build();

Comment: can you please post the whole process how you are creating the popup builder i am trying to follow your code but its not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you implement the context menu. If you use the NatTable way of registering a context menu (which I typically suggest) you can use `PopupMenuBuilder#withEnabledState()` or `PopupMenuBuilder#withVisibleState()`. Inside the implementation of `IMenuItemState` you get the position where the click was performed, which then can be used to get the underlying data.

More information can be found in my blog post about that topic: [NatTable context menus with Eclipse menus](http://blog.vogella.com/2015/02/03/nattable-context-menus-with-eclipse-menus/)

If you want to use E4 menus, you will have to implement some additional logic to extract the necessary information from the click with regards to the NatTable.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please check my update status.

Comment: You need to do this for every menu item you want to handle and that you add via NatTable api. Not sure what your additional question is about.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.It worked so far, thanks ! also, do you know if there is any documentation on the PopupMenuBuilder methods ?

Comment: As of now there is no documentation on that. If the answer solved your issue, please accept the answer.